# I am looking for a way to save all the information of the computers in an active directory principally ComputerName and SerialNUmber for each machine

Tags: powershell, active-directory

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter {OperatingSystem -like "Windows 10*"} -Properties whencreated,serialNumber | Select Name,@{N='serialNumber';E={$_.serialNumber[0]}} | Export-CSV computers.txt -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

Comment: So, what's your question or what are you having trouble with?

Comment: The SerialNumber attribute is not filled in by default and only has a value if you explicitely have set a value there. The serialnumber should come from BIOS: `(Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_bios -ComputerName 'theMachine').SerialNumber`, but that can also be empty..

Comment: The idea is to export in a flat file the serial number and other characteristics through the command to process it and make a technological inventory survey of active and inactive equipment or that in the past have been used in this case I put windows 10 example I can do it manually on each computer but I am not authorized to load policies to do so on all computers in the domain so I choose this option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these steps to save information of computers in active directory.

**Steps 1**: Created a VM (2019 Server) in Azure

**Step 2**:  Go to ADD role and feature and add Active Directory domain service and DNS Sever
[image]

**Step 3**: In features Select Bitlocker drive Encryption and rest keep it as default and install.
Now you able to see the AD DS and DNS server install in your VM.

**Step 4**: Go to the flag on Notification and prompt this server to a domain controller.

**Step 5**: Add a new forest in Deployment Configuration you can take any domain name and do next

[image]

**Step 6** : Enter Password Under Domain Controller option and keep all things as default and install.

**Step 7**:  Restart you VM to apply the policy.

**Step 8**: you can check now your VM under Microsoft.com domain using ‘sysdm.cpl’  in run

**Step 9**: Left click on Windows start button under Windows administrator tool open active directory Users and Computer.

**Step 10**: Add a user under domain Microsoft.com.

**Step 11**: Add dumy computers name and select above user name

[image]

**Step 12**: Enter Get-ADComputer in powershell and filter * able to see the computer and their some metadata.
[image]

**Step 13**: Left click on Windows start button under Windows administrator tool open ADSI edit to the computer metadata (Serial number)

Once open go to more action -> Connect to -> Default naming context->CN- Computers

[image]

**Step 14**: Give the Serial number for computers (any number) and edit the name of your OS to Windows* as per your command given

[image]

**Step 15**: use this below command to get the details..

> Get-ADComputer -Filter {OperatingSystem -like "Windows 10*"}
> -Properties whencreated,serialNumber | Select Name,@{N='serialNumber';E={$_.serialNumber[0]}} | Export-CSV
> computers.txt -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8

[image]

Successfully run the command
and I searched computer.txt file in this PC
Now able to see the computer information in computer.txt file

[image]